# Jquery .click to show proper value from loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have a list of movies and when I click on the title of one I want it to display data that is being extracted from an XML page for that movie title into a new window.

I am looping through an xml file to get the list of movies in the first place

```
$(xml).find('movie').each(function () {
            //Adding the movie title.
            $("body").append("<section class = 'list' id='m" + n + "'><p>" + $(this).attr("name") + "</p></section>");
```

say for instance my first movie is "Terminator 2 Judgment day"

My last attempt was using an array.. but it still just displays the same title for every title I click which is the first one, Terminator.

```
$(xml).find('movie').each(function () {
            //Adding the movie title.
            $("body").append("<section class = 'list' id='m" + n + "'><p>" + $(this).attr("name") + "</p></section>");
            //adding movie website link
            $("#m" + n).append("<a href='" + $(this).find("website").text() + "'>" + $(this).attr("name") + "'s website</a> <br />");
            //adding other movie info in new window
            info.push(($(xml).find("movie").attr("name")));
            $("#m" + n+" p").click(function () {
                mWindow = window.open("", "", "width=500,height=500");
                mWindow.document.write(info[info.length-1]);
});
n++
});
```

Comment: so what is ur question?

Comment: How can I fix this so when I click the second title, it pop's up with information for that second title, same for the rest of the list of titles. As of right now it's only displaying information for the first title, no matter what I click.

Comment: what is the name of title tag in XML movie file?

Comment: <movie name = "Terminator 2 Judgment Day">

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
info.push(($(xml).find("movie").attr("name")));
```

to

```
info.push($(this).attr("name"));
```

...to insert the name attribute from the current item in the loop to that array, instead of the name attribute from the first matched result from `$(xml).find('.movie')`

**Edit:** This is a different approach to what you are probably looking for:

```
$(xml).find('movie').each(function (i, elm) {        
        var $movie = $(elm),
            $section,
            movie = {
                id: 'm' + id,
                name: $movie.attr('name'),
                website: $movie.find('website').text()
            };

        $section = $('<section class="list" id="' + movie.id + '"><p>' + movie.name + '</p><a href="' + movie.website + '">' + movie.name + '\'s website</a><br></section>');
        $section.data('movie', movie);
        $('body').append($section);
});

$('body').on('click', 'section.list p', function (e) {
    var $section = $(e.target).closest('section.list'),
        movie = $section.data('movie'),
        popupText;

    popupText = movie.name + ', ' + movie.website;

    mWindow = window.open("", "", "width=500,height=500");
    mWindow.document.write(popupText);
});
```

First, it loops through `$(xml)`, where it creates and appends the `section` for each movie. Then, some of the movie data gets attached to that section element by using [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

After the loop, it binds **one** click event listener, that detects the closest section from the clicked target, grabs it's data and does something further with it, like opening a popup with the text specified in `popupText`

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are close, it is always returning the last value now though. and if I change info[info.length-1] to say info[info.length-2] it gives me another value which it didn't do before. So I have 5 titles. when I click it seems n is always going be 5.. I need the number of n inside the click function to be the same as the number of the position that title is on the list.

1. movie1 (n is 1 when this is clicked)
2. movie2 (n is 2 when this is clicked)

Comment: You could do `var name = $(this).attr('name');` instead of `info.push($(this).attr('name'));` and then `mWindow.document.write(name);` to pick it up. Anyhow I suggest a different approach, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have put it on fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg77ekoa/8/

Simple window.open() and sending string to the popup from main page. You can send any thing, this is just an example

HTML

```
 <a onclick="show1(this)" id="titanic">Titanic</a>
 <br/>
 <a onclick="show1(this)" id="Tropic Thunder">Tropic Thunder</a>
 <br/>
 <a onclick="show1(this)" id="Hangover">Hangover</a>
```

Javascript

```
 function show1(elem) {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = $(elem).attr("id");

}
```

Comment: I wasn't looking to make it a link to a whole new page. I just want it to be a little pop up containing the information. My issue is when I click for the pop up it's always showing the same result, it's not following the loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
info[n] = ($(this).attr("name")) + more information...
function cHandle(num) {
                    $("#m" + n + " p").click(


 function () { mWindow = window.open("", "", "weight = 500, height=500"); mWindow.document.write(info[num]) }
                    )
            }
            cHandle(n);
```

now n is being passed into the click function properly.